# Scale one dataset to another in Matlab

Tags: matlab, scaling, curve

I have two datasets that they are a particular metric from two images (dat1 and dat2). I want both images to have the same response. The 'ideal' image should look like the first dataset (dat1)

[image]
but the real image looks like the second dataset(dat2).

[image]

I want to try to 'fit' the second dataset to the first dataset. How can i scale dat2 so that it looks like dat1 using Matlab?
I have tried to fit dat1 with different polynomials,exponentials or gaussians and then use the coefficients that i found to fit dat2 but the program fails and it does not fit properly, it gives me a straight zero line.  When i try to fit dat2 using the same shape allowing the coefficients to be free then the program does not give me the ideal shape that i want because it follows the trends of dat2.

Is there any way to fit a dataset to a another set of data instead of a function?

Comment: Are you looking for something like dat2_scaled = rescale(dat2, min(dat1), max(dat1))?

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of this command!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, in this situation, a very common approach consists in normalizing all the vectors between `0` and `1` (interval `[0,1]` with both extremes included). This can be easily achieved as follows:

```
dat1_norm = rescale(dat1);
dat2_norm = rescale(dat2);
```

If you have a version of Matlab greater than or equal to `2017b`, the [rescale](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rescale.html) function is already included by default. Otherwise, it can be defined as follows:

```
function x = rescale(x)
    x = x - min(x);
    x = x ./ max(x);
end
```

In order to achieve the objective you mention (rescaling `dat1` based on minimum and maximum values of `dat2`), you can proceed as [@cemsazara](https://stackoverflow.com/users/986546/cemsazara) said in his comment:

```
dat2_scaled = rescale(dat2,min(dat1),max(dat1));
```

But this is a good solution only as long as you can identify the vector with the larger scale a priori. Otherwise, the risk is to rescale the smaller vector based on the values of the bigger one. That's why the first approach I suggested you may be a more comfortable solution.

In order to adopt this second approach, if your Matlab version is less than `2017b`, you must modify the custom `rescale` function defined above in order to accept two supplementar arguments:

```
function x = rescale(x,mn,mx)
    if (nargin == 1)
        mn = min(x);
        mx = max(x);
    elseif ((nargin == 0) || (nargin == 2))
        error('Invalid number of arguments supplied.');
    end

    x = x - mn;
    x = x ./ mx;
end
```